# Как загружать созданные задачи в todo листе на удаленный сервер и какой сервис для этого выбрать?

Tags: swift

У меня есть приложение, todo лист.

**Моя цель**: загружать созданные задачи "Куда-то" на сервер и "Как-то". Чтобы другой пользователь загрузивший мое приложение смог загрузить эти задачи себе. (то есть получить доступ к моему списку задач)

**Вопрос**: Посоветуйте, куда копать и что изучить для этого.

Comment: Как вариант для этих целей вы можете сделать свое Rest API и get/post запросами получать/отправлять задачи в свою базу данных на хостинге где будет размещено это API. 
На питоне для создания своего API можно использовать FastAPI или Django + restframework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Копайте в сторону Firebase от Google или другого подобного сервиса. 
Грубо говоря, Вам нужна облачная СУБД, позволяющая приложениям хранить и синхронизировать данные между несколькими клиентами. Также там поддерживается обеспечение авторизации пользователей через почту/пароль или через популярные социальные сети.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/444148)

Comment: Поправил. Спасибо.